# Error on installing SharePoint App for Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have simple SharePoint App (addin). I want to deploy it using Visual Studio by pressing F5 (called side loading).

I have created new SharePoint Online tenant and new site collection using Developer template.

Deploy from F5 is working until I add "User Profile" = "Read" permission to app manifest. After that I am receiving error:
"Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app"

[image]

I can deploy it using App Catalog > approve > install on site collection. But fore development I want do this from VS > F5.

Do you know how to resolve the error?